# How to add the css file from server to angular component when state is chaged

Tags: css, angular, ngrx-store

I need to import css file (example.css) from server to the component style when the state is changed. 
It means there are different items and items have different css files in server. when button is clicked, item view component is changed because state  is changed.I can get the path of relevant css file. So I need to add relevant css files from server to the component.

Comment: Why do they need to come from server? It seems what you're trying to achieve is theme changing on a button click. Is that accurate?

Comment: there are two components. one is item-list and other one is item-detail-view. when one item is clicked, item-detail-view is changed relevant to the clicked item. item-detail-view loaded generated html file from server and it showing by using [innerHTML]. there is a css file in the server. I need to import that css file to item-detail-view component.

Comment: Would it be possible to your requirements, to have item-details template in the Angular environment (not coming from server on the item selection), this template having classes that switch the theme, whose CSS rules comes from a component style sheet or global (again not from server) and applying the correct styles by applying classes to the item-details template?  I know for a fact that angular will try to sanitize any HTML, CSS or JS that's sent through HTTP and then is bound to a component to be executed. This is to avoid your system being compromised by injection attacks.